# Cannot View One of my USB Partitions in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, partitioning, recovery

My Windows 10 OS broke down. I decided to split a USB* into two partitions and install Ubuntu on the smallest possible partition. I was going to use the other, larger partition to take the files I want to save from my HDD and put them there, so I could place them on another PC before reinstalling Windows 10 on my HDD.

I am not a pro, so I was quite pleased with myself for having managed to install Ubuntu on a single partition and leaving the other one intact. Now my problem is I can't view that partition I want to use to save my files in Ubuntu, for a reason I don't know. Here's a screenshot of my USB drive in GParted:
[image: GParted]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/b56f/992ejt3vehnynjq9g.jpg))</sub>

Here is a screenshot of my USB drive in Disks:
[image: Disks]
<sub>(source: [mediafire.com](https://www.mediafire.com/convkey/48b1/3r4fy1xyc3y25679g.jpg))</sub>

Excuse me for screenshoting the entire screen. I don't know how to screenshot a single window.

*My USB drive is really a microSDHC drive plugged into an adapter, in case it makes any difference. From my experience, it's always been exactly the same as using a USB stick.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: It seems you have 2 partitions : sdb5 where you have installed Ubuntu, and sdb1 where you have installed its boot loader. Are you looking for a third partition ?

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer Thank you for your comment! I am looking for the partition on which Ubuntu is not installed in the file explorer. It does show up in GParted, though, as you've noticed. For example, when I put my USB stick in a Windows computer, two File Explorer windows pop up. One with Drive D, which is empty and usable, and another one with Drive E, which is unusable because it is a bootable drive. I don't know whether I'm being clear. Feel free to ask for precisions, and thank you again for your interest in helping me out!

Comment: You should have tell us you don’t see the partition on Windows. Have you tried the Windows disk manager ? You will see which partition is assigned to each drive. Note that Windows doesn’t read ext4 filesystems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `sudo fdisk -l` in command line to see the result.
The name of your flash drive should be in the result.

Now edit your mount point with creating a directory: `sudo mkdir /media/name of your flash drive`

Then type `sudo mount /dev/sdb /media/flashdrive` and your flashdrive should mount.

Also refer to these articles:
[https://itsfoss.com/cant-format-usb-disk](https://itsfoss.com/cant-format-usb-disk/)
https://wikibump.com/how-do-i-make-my-usb-visible-in-ubuntu